# recursive function core dumped

Tags: c++, c

I tried to compile the following program

```
void rec(int n)
{
    if(n>0)
   {
        rec(n-1)
        print ("n");

   }
}
```

Here `n` value is a big no. like `1000000`.

o/p is : `segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Can anyone explain what exactly happens here ?
Thanks.

Comment: have a look at the definition of this site's name....

Comment: You have used more stack for the recursive calls than you have available to you.

Comment: Try running it with the debugger and follow the program step-by-step

Comment: You **missed a semi-colon** in your rec(n-1) line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For programs compiled with GCC with default settings stack size is about 2 megabytes. So you are limited in recursive calls by your stack size, because every not-tail recursion function call reduces free stack memory. Thats why you will get stack overflow when `n` is big number.

Comment: thanks for info.. can we increase the stack size for GCC compiler ?

Comment: Yes of course. But you must use special compiler's option, for example: `gcc -Wl,--stack,16777216 -o file.exe file.c` This option increases stack size for current program to 16 MiB.

Comment: pthread utilities (of posix) can report and modify the stack size on linux.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a semicolon and i guess that you want to print the number n and not
n times the letter n. Here is your fixed code.

```
void rec(int n){
    if(n>0){
        rec(n-1);
        printf("%d\n",n);
    }
}
```

To get back to your problem. Recursive function have the problem that each call creates a new stack. You can imagine that with each call you go deeper and deeper and are only climbing back up at the very end.
The number of stacks is limited, so the program will eventually crash if you increase the number of recursive calls.

Comment: Ths missing semicolon is obviously a copying error, otherwise the code won't even compile.

Comment: Each call creates a stack **frame**, not an entire stack.

Comment: @DietmarKühl While there may not be a need to create new stack frames for tail-calls, many implementations will do so anyway. It may depend on compiler options, such as optimization setting.

Comment: _" have the problem that each call creates a new stack."_ Huh?? If so, there wouldn't be a problem.